# ASP.NET Core asp-route-* helpers not rendering link correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following route:

```
    [HttpGet("symbols/{symbol}/{slug}/news")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> News(
        [FromRoute] string symbol,
        [FromRoute] string slug,
        [FromQuery] int perPage,
        [FromQuery] int page)
    {
        ...
    }
```

The route should be something like `symbols/aapl/apple-inc/news`. Now, I also want to include pagination, such as `symbols/aapl/apple-inc/news?page=2&perPage=20`. Therefore symbol and slug are `[FromRoute]` and page and perPage are `[FromQuery]`.

In my view, I have the following link:

```
@for (...)
{
    <a class="page-link"
        asp-action="News"
        asp-controller="Symbols"
        asp-route-symbol="@Model.Symbol.ToLower()"
        asp-route-slug="@Model.CompanyNameSlug"
        asp-route-page="@i"
        asp-route-perPage="@Model.PerPage">
          @i
    </a>
}
```

However this keeps rendering the link incorrectly with the symbol and slug as query parameters: `symbols/news?symbol=aapl&slug=aapl-inc&page=11&perPage=5`

How can I get this link to render as `symbols/aapl/apple-inc/news?page=2&perPage=20`?

Comment: Hi @Marlon,This worked for me in my project.What is your version of asp.net core?And Could you share you Startup.cs?

Comment: @Rena Hi Rena thank you. I am using .net core 3.1. What part of startup cs do you want to see?                 endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Comment: Please check there is no other action with the same name `News`.I add the following code:`[HttpPost("symbols/news")]public async Task<IActionResult> News(string symbol, string slug)`.Then the url in the razor view would render the url like yours.And just change the action name for this post action,you would get the url you want.

Comment: @Rena I made a new project and it also works as expected. In my real project, I don't have another action with the same name like for a HttpPost. When I create a link without the pagination parameters `page` and `perPage`, the News link works. Once I add those pagination parameters, everything becomes part of the query... doesnt make sense.

Comment: Not only post action,did you have same name for get action?

Comment: @Rena I only have one action method named `News`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220528/discussion-between-rena-and-marlon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround like below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{               
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default1",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{symbol?}/{slug?}/{action=Index}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Update:

I found another way,do not use `asp-route-page`.It seems conflict with somthing like `asp-page` in razor pages,change to something like `asp-route-fPage` would be ok.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. Seems like a bug.

Comment: An old bug (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6660)